# reflecting a ray in 2D space

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, physics

In this code, I have two drawn lines, one is hardcoded, the other is a ray that the user creates based on their mouse coordinates.

```java
public class TestPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final Point2D originPoint = new Point(2000 , 100);
    private static final Point2D endPoint = new Point(2500, 500);

    private final Point2D mousePoint;
    private final double slope;
    private final Vector lineVector;
    public TestPanel(){
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();

        MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseListener();
        this.mousePoint = mouseListener.mousePoint;
        addMouseMotionListener(mouseListener);

        double deltaX = originPoint.getX() - endPoint.getX();
        double deltaY = originPoint.getY() - endPoint.getY();
        slope = deltaY == 0 ? 0 : deltaY / deltaX;

        lineVector = new Vector(deltaX , deltaY).getPerpendicularVector();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        int thickness = 30;
        drawCircle(g , thickness , new Point(getWidth() / 2  , getHeight() / 2));

        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
        g.drawLine((int)originPoint.getX() , (int)originPoint.getY() , (int)endPoint.getX() , (int)endPoint.getY());

        g.drawLine(getWidth() / 2 , getHeight() / 2  , (int)mousePoint.getX() , (int)mousePoint.getY());

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        Point2D intersectingPoint = getIntersectingPoint();

        if (intersectingPoint != null
                && intersectingPoint.getX() >= originPoint.getX() && intersectingPoint.getX() <= endPoint.getX()
                && mousePoint.getX() >= intersectingPoint.getX()
        ){
            drawCircle(g , 10 , intersectingPoint);

            double deltaX = (double) getWidth() / 2 - mousePoint.getX();
            double deltaY = (double) getHeight() / 2 - mousePoint.getY();
            Vector mouseVector = new Vector(deltaX , deltaY);

            try {
                double angleBetween = mouseVector.angleBetween(lineVector);

                g.setFont(new Font("Arial" , Font.BOLD , 30));
                String angleBetweenStr = String.valueOf(angleBetween);
                int width = g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(angleBetweenStr);
                g.drawString(angleBetweenStr , getWidth() - width - 10 , getHeight() - 100);

                angleBetween *= 2;
                angleBetween  += 2*(90 - angleBetween);
                angleBetween += mouseVector.getAngle();

                // making the angle be the same as the line vector and then adding 90 - angleBetween to reflect the ray back
                int steps = 50;
                double sinTheta = Math.sin(angleBetween) * steps;
                double cosTheta = Math.cos(angleBetween) * steps;

                g.drawLine((int) intersectingPoint.getX(), (int) intersectingPoint.getY(), (int) (intersectingPoint.getX() + cosTheta), (int) (intersectingPoint.getY() + sinTheta));
            } catch (InvalidPropertiesFormatException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }


    private Point2D getIntersectingPoint(){
        double deltaX2 = (double) getWidth() / 2 - mousePoint.getX();
        double deltaY2 = (double) getHeight() / 2 - mousePoint.getY();

        double slope2 = deltaY2 == 0 ? 0 : deltaY2 / deltaX2;

        double xEquationMouse = mousePoint.getY() - slope2 * mousePoint.getX();
        double xEquationLine = originPoint.getY() - this.slope * originPoint.getX();

        double x = this.slope - slope2;
        double x1 = xEquationMouse - xEquationLine;

        if (x == 0)
            return null;

        return new Point2D.Double(x1 / x , this.slope * (x1 / x) + xEquationLine);
    }
    private void drawCircle(Graphics graphics , int rad , Point2D originPoint){
        graphics.fillOval((int)originPoint.getX()- (rad / 2), (int)originPoint.getY() - (rad / 2) , rad , rad);
    }

    private  class MouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
        private final Point2D mousePoint = new Point(0,0);
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            mousePoint.setLocation(e.getX() , e.getY());
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            mousePoint.setLocation(e.getX() , e.getY());
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);

        frame.setContentPane(new TestPanel());

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here is the class for the vector:

```java
public class Vector {

    private double[] components;
    private double magnitude;
    private double angle;

    public Vector(double... components) {
        if (components.length <= 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Components length must be larger than 1");

        // preventing user from changing the components of the vector
        this.components = Arrays.copyOf(components, components.length);

        this.magnitude = calculateMagnitude();

        setAngle(components);
    }

    // only works for a 2D vector
    // constructing a unit vector with a specific angle, this angle can be changed after initialization using the setAngle() method
    public Vector(int angle) {
        magnitude=1;

        setAngle(angle);
    }

    public void normalizeVector() {
        if (magnitude != 1){
            for (int i = 0; i < components.length; i++)
                components[i] /= magnitude;

            magnitude = 1;
        }
    }

    public Vector getPerpendicularVector(){
        double[] perpendicularComponents = new double[this.getDimensions()];

        double componentTemp = components[0];
        perpendicularComponents[0] = -components[1];
        perpendicularComponents[1] = componentTemp;

        for (int i = 2 ; i < perpendicularComponents.length ; i++)
            perpendicularComponents[i] = 0;

        return new Vector(perpendicularComponents);
    }

    /*
    a · b
    ----
   |a|·|b|
     */
    public double angleBetween(Vector vector) throws InvalidPropertiesFormatException {
        double dotProduct = this.dot(vector);
        double magnitudesProduct = magnitude * vector.magnitude;
        double cosTheta = dotProduct / magnitudesProduct;
        double angleInRadians = Math.acos(cosTheta);

        return Math.toDegrees(angleInRadians);
    }

    public static double dot(double[] aComponents, double[] bComponents) throws InvalidPropertiesFormatException {
        if (aComponents.length != bComponents.length)
            throw new InvalidPropertiesFormatException("Vector a and Vector b must have the same components length");

        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < aComponents.length; i++)
            sum += aComponents[i] * bComponents[i];;

        return sum;
    }

    public double dot(Vector vector) throws InvalidPropertiesFormatException {
        return dot(this, vector);
    }

    public double dot(double... components) throws InvalidPropertiesFormatException {
        return dot(this.components, components);
    }

    public static double dot(Vector aVector, Vector bVector) throws InvalidPropertiesFormatException {
        return dot(aVector.components, bVector.components);
    }

    public double getMagnitude() {
        return magnitude;
    }

    public double[] getComponents() {
        return components;
    }

    public double getComponentAt(int i) {
        if (i >= components.length || i < 0)
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(String.format("Index %s out of bounds for %s component vector", i, components.length));

        return components[i];
    }

    public int getDimensions(){
        return components.length;
    }

    public double getAngle(){
        return angle;
    }

    public void setAngle(double angle){
        this.angle = angle;

        this.components = new double[]{Math.sin(angle) , Math.cos(angle)};
    }

    public void setAngle(double... components){
        angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(components[0] / components[1]));
    }

    private double calculateMagnitude() {
        double sum = 0.0;

        for (double component : components)
            sum += Math.pow(component , 2);

        return Math.sqrt(sum);
    }
}
```

Now, When I run this application, and intersect the hardcoded line, a new line should be drawn that is reflected by the same incident angle. Instead, the new line just rotates with each new angle the user gives, like it's rolling. Why is that? and how do I fix this so the the new line is reflected?

Comment: `frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);` Thank you for making that full screen so the window frame was inaccessible.  I had to use the Task Manager to kill it.

Comment: Just looking at your `drawCircle` method in your `TestPanel` class, you input the diameter of the circle and call it the rad, which looks like it's short for radius.  This level of naming confusion does not bode well for debugging your code.

Comment: Would you add a screen shot?